# SQL DataTable not returning SQL DataSet values C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, datatable, ado.net

I am trying to import an XML file to SQL table using C#. The problem is that the SQL DataSet is returning a value but for some reason it is not putting the values into the SQL DataTable. Here is my code:

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
     ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/state.xml"));
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();

     dt = ds.Tables["state"];
     con.Open();

     using(SqlBulkCopy bc = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
     {
           bc.DestinationTableName = "StateIncorporated";
           bc.ColumnMappings.Add("name", "State");
           bc.ColumnMappings.Add("abbreviation", "Abbreviation");
           bc.ColumnMappings.Add("country_id", "Country_ID");
           bc.WriteToServer(dt);
     }
}
```

I have used this same exact code about a couple hours ago with another XML file and it worked perfectly. This new XML file is written the same way as the one before it. When I debug in Visual Studio and I check the values in the DataSet, it is correct. So everything is correct yet not working and it is frustrating. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I see 2 things wrong you can change this by changing the following 
`ds.ReadXML(Server.MapPath("~state.xml"), XmlReadMode.InferSchema);` 
`dt = dsTables[0];`  also when you but break points in the code.. does `ds` have an initial value..? if so then the dataset's tables are `0` based so you access it by dataset.Tables[0]` since you never gave ds a table name if you did please show that relevant / related code as well.

Comment: Perfect! That worked but why did it work before with the same exact code but reading a different XML file? If you post the answer I will mark it as the answer.

Comment: that's because you were trying to access a DataSets.DataTable by the name of "state" which does not look like you named it so you need to do it by the default access which is `ds.Tables[0]` and because you do not specify the `XML Schema` you need to use the `XmlReadMode.InferSchema` to have it determine the schema assuming that the xml has been properly formatted but I've not run into any issues using this approacah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ds.ReadXML(Server.MapPath("~state.xml"), XmlReadMode.InferSchema); 
dt = ds.Tables[0];
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: not a problem.. I saw that immediately thank goodness I've ran into this before glad I could be of assistance.